# Data Wrangling - R - Want to remove rows which corresponds between fyweek and launchweek

Tags: r, dataframe, data-science, data-manipulation

Looking for a solution to remove rows for the weeks which are coming between FY_Week and Launch_Week. Each row is for a product_ID and look like the below table:-

Objective is - not to consider rows shaded in yellow (records which belong to weeks which are between fy_week and launch week). and we want to aggregate avg sales for the same.Looking for a solution in r. Thanks in advance :)
[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhNrr.png)

Comment: you can use ifelse do this.

Comment: Your link does not contain a dataset - it contains only a picture with some numbers. If you want us to do your work, you need at least to provide the raw material.

Comment: I posted an answer, but I agree with the above comment for next time

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer using dplyr.

```
library(dplyr)
```

Recreating your data:

```
data <- tibble(
  product_id = rep(c("abc1", "abc2"), each = 3),
  FYWeek = rep(c(20, 22), each = 3),
  Launch_Week = rep(c(30, 28), each = 3),
  Week = c(21, 31, 32, 25, 29, 26),
  Sale = c(453, 408, 473, 466, 473, 412)
)
```

Discard the rows not meeting your conditions and getting the mean of the `Sale` of remaining rows:

```
data %>% 
  filter(Week < FYWeek | Week > Launch_Week) %>%
  mutate(avg = mean(Sale))

# A tibble: 3 x 6
  product_id FYWeek Launch_Week  Week  Sale   avg
  <chr>       <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 abc1           20          30    31   408  451.
2 abc1           20          30    32   473  451.
3 abc2           22          28    29   473  451.
```

Comment: Note really sure what you meant with "and we want to aggregate avg sales for the same". I interpreted it as you wanting the mean for the sale of the selected rows. That's what the `avg` variable gives (with the same value everywhere of course since it is the mean)